# Sequelize.js setter function not working as I expect

Tags: javascript, node.js, database, orm, sequelize.js

I'm having trouble using the setter functions on my Sequelize js model properties.

What I want to do is when one property is given a value use that value to populate another property in the table at the same time.

In my model this is the code I have for the property in question...

```
date_time_paid: {
  type:DataTypes.DATE,
  set(val) {
    const date = new Date(val);
    this.setDataValue('date_time_paid', val);  // set the the current property
    this.setDataValue('month_paid', `${date.getFullYear()}-${(date.getMonth() + 1)}`);  //also set another property on the same row
  },
},
```

What I expect to happen is for the `date_time_paid` column to store the raw value and the `month_paid` column to store a string derived from it. But when I run my seeder to populate the table with test data the value for the month_paid column remains null.

1. Is this the correct use of a setter function?
2. If it is what have I done wrong that means it's not working?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need a just a getter. Forget about `date_time_paid` and make getter for `month_paid`:

```
get month_paid(){
    const date = new Date(this.date_time_paid);
    return `${date.getFullYear()}-${(date.getMonth() + 1)}`;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that might work but unfortunately it's not what I need: Sequelize is not the only method by which the database will be queried... other places will need the same information. Also, as far as I can tell, getters won't work if you're using the `raw: true` flag on your query which i need to because of the size of the results set I expect in some cases.

Comment: right, have you tried `setterMethods`? . I don't know any difference though, except the setter defined in property takes precedence

Comment: So, I think the code here turns out to be correct but the problem is the way that I was populating the database table by using the `bulkInsert` method in my seeder. 

This appears to skip the model creation stage so setters are not applied. <shrug>